Configure Apache to apply path info behavior to index.php directory index too
Why is AcceptPathInfo applied when changing the filename, yet isn't when I change the path? More concretely, I can get it to rewrite with:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} (.*):\g1(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php%2 [END]

And given that /aaa.php exists, I get:
https://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc -> https://example.com/aaa.php/bbb/ccc

Yet when I try it with:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}:%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} (.*):\g1(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php%2 [END]

And given that /aaa/index.php exists, I get:
https://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc -> 404 Not Found

I tried logging with LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6, but all I saw is that RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f was checked for %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/aaa.php, as if it automatically tried all potential pathnames in case of %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php, but not %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php.
Is it possible to get this to work? That given /aaa/index.php existing I would get:
https://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc -> https://example.com/aaa/index.php/bbb/ccc

Just like the .php rewrite above.

Not sure what that third condition does, what is the \g1(.*) at the end there? Is that supposed to call some function, is it somehow rewritemap related?

Since RewriteCond are joined with an implicit AND, I am not even sure how the first part works, how %{REQUEST_FILENAME} and %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php could satisfy -f at the same time? Wondering if this is a side effect of MultiViews being enabled.

@Cbroe It is a backreference and (.*) is just a normal catchall capture group. I use it here to be able to refer to the value of REQUEST_FILENAME in my match, while not being able to interpolate variables in regexes as far as I could find. And you are correct, that seems to be a typo, I had my condition be RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f and then had a RewriteRule ^ - [S=N] where N was the RewriteRule's I wanted to skip, but should have a ! there.

MultiViews was not enabled and I just rechecked with disabling it explicitly, but no change, so it probably was already disabled to begin with. Also MultiViews would only have been a problem if it went with some other file than I expected rather than just not matching.
